# Style Link with styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, styled-components

I'm using `styled-components` in the TypeScript React application, and I have a Router on top of it.

Is it possible to style `Link` element from `react-router-dom` with styled components?

Something like this one maybe:

```
  const HeaderLink = styled.Link`
    background-color: hotpink;
  `
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, just pass `Link` as argument to the `styled` function:

```
const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
   color: green;
`;
```

Comment: Just remember to `import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`